# I keep receiving -2 as my updated salary

Tags: c++, arrays, function, class, constructor

I am doing the following with my program:

> > 1) Write the class definition for a class named Employee with name and salary as employee objects. The class contains two member functions: the constructor and a function that allows a program to assign values to the data members.
> >
> > 2) Add two member functions to the Employee class. One member function should allow any program using an employee object to view the contents of the salary data member. The other member function should allow the program to view the contents of the employee name data member.
> >
> > 3) Add another member function to the Employeeclass. The member function should calculate an employee objects new salary, based on a raise percentage provided by the program using the object. Before calculating the raise, the member function should verify that the raise percentage is greater than or equal to zero. If the raise percentage is less than zero, the member function should display an error message.
> >
> > 4) Write a main function that will create an array of employee objects, assign values to the objects, display the names and current salaries for all objects, ask user for the raise percentage and then calculate and display new salaries for all objects.

However, I receive -2 as my new salary after I input the data from the keyboard. I figured another set of eyes could see what I can't and would highly appreciate if someone can lend a hand, or at least steer me in the right direction. Perhaps it is a logic error, or something wrong with my declarations. Thank you for your time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;



class EMPLOYEE
{
public:
    EMPLOYEE();//
    EMPLOYEE(string name, int salary);//


public:
  string name;//name to be input
  int salary;//salary to be input
  int percentage_raise;
  int updated_salary;



public:
int enter_values();
int output_values();
int NEW_SALARY();


};


//default constructor
EMPLOYEE::EMPLOYEE()
{
    name = "";
    salary = 0;
}

//constructor with name/salary variables
EMPLOYEE::EMPLOYEE(string NAME, int SALARY)
{
    name= NAME;
    salary= SALARY;
}

//name and salary to be input...
int EMPLOYEE::enter_values()
{ cout<<"Enter name and salary: ";
  cin>> name;
  cin>>salary;


  return 0;
}

//output

int EMPLOYEE::output_values()
{ cout<<"Name: "<<name<<endl;
  cout<<"Salary: "<<salary<<endl;

  return 0;
}


//
int EMPLOYEE::NEW_SALARY()
{

    if ( percentage_raise >= 0)
    { int updated_salary;

        int raise= (salary *percentage_raise)/100;
    updated_salary += raise;

}

else if(percentage_raise< 0)
{ cout<<"Error Message"<<endl;

}

 return 0;
}



int main()
{
   EMPLOYEE employees[100];
   EMPLOYEE percent_to_be_raised;


   int i;
   for(i =0 ;i<100 ; i++)
   { employees[i]=EMPLOYEE();
     employees[i].enter_values();
     employees[i].name;
     employees[i].salary;
    // employees[i].NEW_SALARY();
     employees[i].output_values();



 cout<<"How much should the salary be raised by?"<<endl;
       cin>>percent_to_be_raised.percentage_raise;

  cout<<"-----------------------------"<<endl;

  cout<<employees[i].name <<"'s new salary is "<<percent_to_be_raised.updated_salary<<endl;


   }








}
```

Comment: Please debug your program to narrow down what's gong wrong wth your code before [asking here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)!

Comment: There are several things to repair here.  If the answer below does not guide the OP, then I will delete it.

Comment: @CPlusPlusOOAandD The OP should probably follow my advice, and fix all the errors step by step. Your answer might lead to endless follow up questions placed as comments by the OP :-/ ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well, if there is no indication the OP is reading the post, then my answer will be gone shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the OP coding style convention is used to assist the OP.  I am aware of the proper naming convention for classes, member functions, and class data members (e.g. see the answer by Captain Giraffe for more).

Inside of:

```
int EMPLOYEE::NEW_SALARY()
{

    if ( percentage_raise >= 0)
    { int updated_salary;

        int raise= (salary *percentage_raise)/100;
        updated_salary += raise;

    }
} // added this to close the function properly
```

there is a locally declared variable, which is typed identically to the `public` access data member of the same name.  What is the intention here?

Most likely it should be coded like so:

```
int EMPLOYEE::NEW_SALARY()
{

    if ( percentage_raise >= 0)
    { 

        int raise = (salary *percentage_raise)/100;
        updated_salary += raise;

    }
} // added this to close the function properly
```

There are design considerations for having all class member data public, as well as having an integer for a percentage.  From the calculation above, it looks like only values of one, two, three, etc. are allowed for the percentage number.  What is the class supposed to do if a raise is 3.75 percent?

The constructor has to set ALL class data members to something meaningful too.  For example, the  `percentage_raise` and `updated_salary` variables are ignored.  Most likely the default constructor has to be updated to:

```
//default constructor
EMPLOYEE::EMPLOYEE()
{
    name = "";
    salary = 0;
    percentage_raise = 0;
    updated_salary = 0;
}
```

The name and salary constructor has to be updated too.  It should probably look like (using the style convention posted by the OP):

```
//constructor with name/salary variables
EMPLOYEE::EMPLOYEE(string NAME, int SALARY)
{
    name = NAME;
    salary = SALARY;
    percentage_raise = 0;
    updated_salary = salary;
}
```

Comment: NEW_SALARY() is never called in OP's sample.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe  It is commented out in the body of the for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewrite this quite alot.

A few pointers:

```
   EMPLOYEE percent_to_be_raised;
```

Is completely off base. The task states that this calculation should be done in an employee member function. I.e. the raise should be performed as

```
Employee alfred;
std::cin>> alfred.salary;
double raise;
std::cin>> raise;
alfred.raise_salary(raise);  // this is what the task asks for.
```

Use a naming convention.

```
Employee
```

is fine for a c++ class with a capitalized class name convention.  `EMPLOYEE` is not; this looks like a macro name.

Member function usually starts with non-capitalized
    Employee::new_salary( the_salary );

Follow the examples you have available from the course material.

Of course

```
 employees[i].name;
 employees[i].salary;
```

Does not do anything. Please review your code in detail and start at the first spot you don't understand.